# How to selectively read xml file

Tags: xml, python-2.7

How to selectively read the xml below so that when confronted with tags  with similar names, the xml reader would skip the first tag.

```
<paraphrase_candidates source_description="id:9249">    
    <annotation author="87" is_paraphrase="true" source_description="id:18689" >
        <phenomenon type="lex_same_polarity" projection="local"                                        source_description="id:5528">
            <snippet id="16488" >
                <scope offset="125" length="4"/>
            </snippet>
            <snippet id="16489" >
                <scope offset="71" length="11"/>
            </snippet>
        </phenomenon>
        <phenomenon type="syn_diathesis" source_description="id:5536">
            <snippet id="16488" >
                <scope offset="32" length="92"/>
            </snippet>
                <scope offset="0" length="70"/>
        </phenomenon>
    </annotation>
</paraphrase_candidates>
```

Specifically,  I would like to skip the first phenomenon tag and retrieve the scope attribute of the second phenomenon tag.

```
My attempts
for x in root.findall('scope'):
    print x.attrib[0]
```

> Output: empty

expected output:`{offset="32" length="92"} and {offset="0" length="70}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root.findall('scope')` returned empty because `scope` aren't direct child of `root` in your XML. Using `.//scope` instead (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)) will get you all `scope` elements in the XML.

To get only `scope` elements from the 2nd `phenomenon`, you can use position index predicate (note that XPath position index start from 1, not 0) :

```
root.findall('.//phenomenon[2]//scope')
```

Test codes :

```
>>> raw = '''<paraphrase_candidates source_description="id:9249">                            
...     <annotation author="87" is_paraphrase="true" source_description="id:18689" >         
...         <phenomenon type="lex_same_polarity" projection="local"                          
              source_description="id:5528">                                                  
...             <snippet id="16488" >                                                        
...                 <scope offset="125" length="4"/>                                         
...             </snippet>                                                                   
...             <snippet id="16489" >                                                        
...                 <scope offset="71" length="11"/>                                         
...             </snippet>                                                                   
...         </phenomenon>                                                                    
...         <phenomenon type="syn_diathesis" source_description="id:5536">                   
...             <snippet id="16488" >                                                        
...                 <scope offset="32" length="92"/>                                         
...             </snippet>                                                                   
...                 <scope offset="0" length="70"/>                                          
...         </phenomenon>                                                                    
...     </annotation>                                                                        
... </paraphrase_candidates>'''                                                              
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as et                                                  
>>> root = et.fromstring(raw)                                                                
>>> for x in root.findall('.//phenomenon[2]//scope'):
...     print x.attrib
...
{'length': '92', 'offset': '32'}
{'length': '70', 'offset': '0'}
```

Comment: how can make it work if the xml file has an http preceeding; 
`<corpus xmlns="http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="P4P" version="1.0" lng="en" xsi:schemaLocation="http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus.xsd">`

Comment: @Boby, search for "xpath default namespace". It's not called "an http" it's called a namespace. And please don't use comments to ask follow-up questions: raise a new question. Oh, and if the answer worked you should accept it (click on the tick-mark).